# JTextField doesn't respond

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jtextfield

I work with Swing and WindowsBuilder, the eclipse environment is running on the unix server.

Every time I run the program and try to copy paste some data from another window to `JTextField` in the program the `JTextField` stops responding.

I mean I press play in the Eclipse, the form is up and the `JTextField` is responding but then I press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>  to move to another window, press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> and then <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> again to go back to the running program but the `JTextField` doesn't respond to anything.

help someone?

Thanks

well here is the code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultFormatter;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JButton;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;
import javax.swing.SpinnerNumberModel;
import javax.swing.DropMode;


public class MainPage extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private String sSpe1;
    private String sSpe2;
    private JTextField txtTomB1;
    private JTextField txtTomB2;
    private JTextField txtTomB3;
    private JTextField txtTomB4;
    private JTextField txtTomB5;
    private JTextField txtPotB1;
    private JTextField txtPotB2;
    private JTextField txtPotB3;
    private JTextField txtPotB4;
    private JTextField txtPotB5;
    private JTextField txtAraB1;
    private JTextField txtAraB2;
    private JTextField txtAraB3;
    private JTextField txtAraB4;
    private JTextField txtAraB5;
    private JTextField[] arrTomBaits = new JTextField[5];
    private JTextField[] arrPotBaits = new JTextField[5];
    private JTextField[] arrAraBaits = new JTextField[5];
    private JLabel lblNote;
    private JLabel lblChooseLocation;
    private JTextField txtLocation;
    private JButton btnBrowse;
    private boolean bCanContinue;
    private JSpinner spinner;
    private JSpinner spnRValueBelow;


    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    MainPage frame = new MainPage();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public MainPage()
    {
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 551, 609);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setSize(600, 1000);
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        txtTomB1 = new JTextField();
        txtTomB1.setDropMode(DropMode.INSERT);
        txtTomB1.setBounds(20, 308, 86, 20);
        contentPane.add(txtTomB1);
        txtTomB1.setColumns(10);
        arrTomBaits[0] = txtTomB1;

        txtTomB2 = new JTextField();
        txtTomB2.setDropMode(DropMode.INSERT);
        txtTomB2.setColumns(10);
        txtTomB2.setBounds(20, 339, 86, 20);
        contentPane.add(txtTomB2);
        arrTomBaits[1] = txtTomB2;

        txtTomB3 = new JTextField();
        txtTomB3.setDropMode(DropMode.INSERT);
        txtTomB3.setColumns(10);
        txtTomB3.setBounds(20, 370, 86, 20);
        contentPane.add(txtTomB3);
        arrTomBaits[2] = txtTomB3;

        txtTomB4 = new JTextField();
        txtTomB4.setDropMode(DropMode.INSERT);
        txtTomB4.setColumns(10);
        txtTomB4.setBounds(20, 401, 86, 20);
        contentPane.add(txtTomB4);
        arrTomBaits[3] = txtTomB4;

        txtTomB5 = new JTextField();
        txtTomB5.setDropMode(DropMode.INSERT);
        txtTomB5.setColumns(10);
        txtTomB5.setBounds(20, 432, 86, 20);
        contentPane.add(txtTomB5);
        arrTomBaits[4] = txtTomB5;

        txtPotB1 = new JTextField();
        txtPotB1.setDropMode(DropMode.INSERT);
        txtPotB1.setColumns(10);
        txtPotB1.setBounds(122, 308, 86, 20);
        contentPane.add(txtPotB1);
        arrPotBaits[0] = txtPotB1;

        txtPotB2 = new JTextField();
        txtPotB2.setDropMode(DropMode.INSERT);
        txtPotB2.setColumns(10);
        txtPotB2.setBounds(122, 339, 86, 20);
        contentPane.add(txtPotB2);
        arrPotBaits[1] = txtPotB2;

        txtPotB3 = new JTextField();
        txtPotB3.setDropMode(DropMode.INSERT);
        txtPotB3.setColumns(10);
        txtPotB3.setBounds(122, 370, 86, 20);
        contentPane.add(txtPotB3);
        arrPotBaits[2] = txtPotB3;

        txtPotB4 = new JTextField();
        txtPotB4.setDropMode(DropMode.INSERT);
        txtPotB4.setColumns(10);
        txtPotB4.setBounds(122, 401, 86, 20);
        contentPane.add(txtPotB4);
        arrPotBaits[3] = txtPotB4;

        txtPotB5 = new JTextField();
        txtPotB5.setDropMode(DropMode.INSERT);
        txtPotB5.setColumns(10);
        txtPotB5.setBounds(122, 432, 86, 20);
        contentPane.add(txtPotB5);
        arrPotBaits[4] = txtPotB5;

        txtAraB1 = new JTextField();
        txtAraB1.setDropMode(DropMode.INSERT);
        txtAraB1.setColumns(10);
        txtAraB1.setBounds(234, 308, 86, 20);
        contentPane.add(txtAraB1);
        arrAraBaits[0] = txtAraB1;

        txtAraB2 = new JTextField();
        txtAraB2.setDropMode(DropMode.INSERT);
        txtAraB2.setColumns(10);
        txtAraB2.setBounds(234, 339, 86, 20);
        contentPane.add(txtAraB2);
        arrAraBaits[1] = txtAraB2;

        txtAraB3 = new JTextField();
        txtAraB3.setDropMode(DropMode.INSERT);
        txtAraB3.setColumns(10);
        txtAraB3.setBounds(234, 370, 86, 20);
        contentPane.add(txtAraB3);
        arrAraBaits[2] = txtAraB3;

        txtAraB4 = new JTextField();
        txtAraB4.setDropMode(DropMode.INSERT);
        txtAraB4.setColumns(10);
        txtAraB4.setBounds(234, 401, 86, 20);
        contentPane.add(txtAraB4);
        arrAraBaits[3] = txtAraB4;

        txtAraB5 = new JTextField();
        txtAraB5.setDropMode(DropMode.INSERT);
        txtAraB5.setColumns(10);
        txtAraB5.setBounds(234, 432, 86, 20);
        contentPane.add(txtAraB5);
        arrAraBaits[4] = txtAraB5;

        txtLocation = new JTextField();
        txtLocation.setBounds(20, 492, 248, 20);
        contentPane.add(txtLocation);
        txtLocation.setColumns(10);
    }
}
```

the problem is with all the txtARAB#, txtTomB#, txtPotB# and txtLocation

Comment: Make sure you don't block the GUI-thread.

Comment: can you explain please?  I don't have another thread when I'm moving to the other window.  the truth is I'm only using Process and not threads in the program.  BTW all the other buttons are working when I go back to the program window, only the JTextField doesn't

Comment: @AdiGazeat there isn't any exception error? maybe some awt event error

Comment: no nothing...  what I do right now is just type the data I need in the moment I run the program without copy paste it from a different window.

Comment: Please provide [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). As I or anybody else could make a simple example which most likely will not have this problem...

Comment: what do you need exactly?  the code?  a picture of the form?

Comment: @AdiGazeat read the link in my comment (i.e click [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)), but yes a Short Self-Contained Correct Example which reproduces the problem, with the minimum amount of code as possible.

Comment: *if there any syntax errors (missing {} and so, ignore it, I didn't checked when I copy-pasted the code to here and the project compiles just fine.* Please it must be compilable or once again we have to go editing things to get the code working when it should work and demonstrate the problem from a simple copy and paste, so unless your problem is missing brackets, add them!

Comment: 1) No need for 
        `setDropMode(DropMode.INSERT);` call unless you are doing some drag and drop of text 2) Please use a [`Layout Manager`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) other than `Absolute`! 3) Why worry about the *contentpane*? dont set your own simply add components via `JFrame#add(..)` which will add components to its default *contentpane* (`JFrame#getContentPane()`) 4) Lastly dont extend `JFrame` class unnecessarily, simply create an instance of `JFrame` via new `JFrame()` and call methods on that instance

Comment: Try it without `setDropMode`.

Comment: tried it - still not working

Comment: BTW on windows it works perfectly fine

Comment: @Adi So you're not having any problems on Windows?  Then which operating system are you having the problem on?  OSX? Linux?

Comment: @Mike Clark .. read ques.. its unix server

Comment: @Dreamer Which Unix?  Java runs on many Unixes:  Mac OS X, Solaris, AIX, HPUX, ...

Comment: @Mike Clark you have to ask the questioner that.. he/she has only specified 'unix server' in the ques

Comment: @Dreamer I did ask the questioner that.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked out the code yet. But my simple guess is when you "ALT + TAB" back to the swing form your preferred textfield may have lost **focus**.. so what you can do is add a WindowFocusListener to your JFrame and whenever the focus is gained, transfer the focus to the preferred textbox.. like this..

```
public class TestFrame extends JFrame {

   private JTextField txtBox1; 
   private JTextField txtBox2;

   public TestFrame() {

     // init the components and add to frame

     this.addWindowFocusListener(new WindowFocusListener() {

            @Override
            public void windowLostFocus(WindowEvent arg0) {
                System.out.println("Window Focus Lost");                
            }

            @Override
            public void windowGainedFocus(WindowEvent arg0) {
                System.out.println("Window Focus Gained");  
                txtBox2.requestFocus();
            }
        });

   }

}
```

So now everytime you get back to your Jframe your textbox would have got focus..

Comment: ok.. BTW your code works perfect in my windows machine.. i suggest you try running your code in another system with unix/linux then see if this persists.. may be its a momentary lag or hang in your system..